# Duplicate entries when start new member of Hazelcast cluster

Tags: hazelcast, persistent-storage, hazelcast-imap

I implement my `MapStore` to save entries to database (external datastore), but there a issue of starting new node when old member storing entries to database. Firstly, cluster A has only `Member1`.

Client puts 20K entries to the cluster then Member1 starts saving entries by batch to database (write-behind mode). When 5K entries has been saved to database (not finish whole 20K entries) I start Member2 to join the cluster A

--> Member2 received about 10K entries (result of repartition) , Member2 stores them to the database, despite of this 10K entries has been saved to database by Member1

This leads to duplicate 10K records in database (10K from Member2). This is not occurs when 2 members are both ready when start putting  entries from client, or in write-though mode

Please tell me why? This is my code

```java
/**
 *
 * @author Mina Mimi
 */
public class SmsLogMapStore implements MapStore<String, SmsLog>, MapLoaderLifecycleSupport {

    Connection conn;

    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SmsLogMapStore.class.getSimpleName());

    @Override
    public synchronized void store(String k, SmsLog v) {
        logger.info("===write one >>>:" + v.getContent());
        String sql = "insert into smslog (content) values (?)";
        PreparedStatement st = null;
        try {
            st = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            st.setString(1, v.getContent());
            st.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SmsLogMapStore.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                st.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SmsLogMapStore.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        logger.info("Finished write one >>>");
    }
    @Override
    public synchronized void storeAll(Map<String, SmsLog> map) {
        logger.info("Write batch:" + map.size());
        String sql = "insert into smslog (content) values (?)";
        PreparedStatement st = null;
        try {
            st = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            for (Map.Entry<String, SmsLog> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                SmsLog v = entry.getValue();
                logger.info("===Writing(k,v):" + key + "," + v + " from batch");
                st.setString(1, v.getContent());
                st.addBatch();
            }
            st.executeBatch();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SmsLogMapStore.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                st.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SmsLogMapStore.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        logger.info("Finished Write batch >>>");
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(String k) {
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteAll(Collection<String> clctn) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        for (String key : clctn) {
            delete(key);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public SmsLog load(String k) {        
        return new SmsLog();
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, SmsLog> loadAll(Collection<String> clctn) {
        logger.info("############loadAll");
        HashMap<String, SmsLog> result = new HashMap<String, SmsLog>();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized Iterable<String> loadAllKeys() {
        List<String> keys = new LinkedList<String>();
        return keys;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(HazelcastInstance hi, Properties prprts, String string) {
        try {
            conn = getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SmsLogMapStore.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SmsLogMapStore.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test_imdb", "root", "");
        return conn;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `storeAll()` doesn’t signal the progress back to Hazelcast, Hazelcast has no means of restoring the write operation from where it left off. It must simply restart it from the scratch on the new set of cluster members.

As such, the `storeAll()` implementation should be made idempotent. E.g. it must be ready to survive multiple invocations on the same keys. The simplest approach is to use a UPSERT-style operation to write data to the storage. If the record was already written, the DB will just ignore it (or rewrite it with the same value).

If you need to store big batches of data, consider using the [data pipeline](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/latest/pipelines/overview). Jet can resume from a specific source offset after a failure or a topology change, the data operation isn't just restarted. It will be a solution with more moving parts, so don’t use it unless it’s really a concern. 20k keys is kind of tiny dataset.

What is the storage system you are using? Does it support upserts by any means?

Comment: Thank you for the answer

What is the storage system you are using? Does it support upserts by any means? ==> More than hundred millions of records, so it does not support upsert - style (check before insert), 20K is only a number of samples to verify the result.
Data pipeline ==> I will consider this solution.
But I wonder that with write-behind mode, I cannot confident about the data inserted to external storage (database), espescially in time restart, start, shutdown a members of cluster.

Comment: @lamxung55 can the remote storage do multiple writes in a transaction? Hazelcast calls storeAll() for a batch of entries. It either succeeds (storeAll completes) or it fails and restarts (for example due to the cluster topology change). Implementing storeAll() code as a single transaction would solve your problem.

Comment: Single transaction or multiple transaction, even only writing an output to file only are the same. You can imagine there are many many transactions per second (high TPS) so storeAll will delay and cannot finish before new member joins

Comment: Your app updates entries in Hazelcast Map. MapStore stores the updates to a remote system (usually database). If you enable write delay, Hazelcast invokes your MapLoader's storeAll with batches of entries for better performance. If the storeAll doesn't complete for a specific batch due to change in cluster topology, it's rescheduled by Hazelcast. That leads to duplicit writes. Implement your storeAll as a single write transaction to the remote database (manually commit once all entries are stored). If storeAll can't finish, the transaction will be rolled back by the database.Can your db do tx?

Comment: Yes, DB supports Tx, but Implement my storeALl as a single write transaction, there're still many entries waitting to saved (dirty entries), this leads dupplicate when new member joins

Comment: @lamxung55 could you join the Hazelcast community Slack? https://slack.hazelcast.com/ Let's iterate on solution there and paste the answer to SO once we're sure.

Answer (score 1):

There is no distributed coordination for write-behind. Means adding or removing nodes can cause data loss or duplications, no guarantee here, current implementation is working as a best effort manner.

If you ask for a workaround, you can have a distributed id supplier and before putting objects in IMap, you can set an id to it from this supplier, when map-store is saving the object, duplications can be detected by the help of this id.

Comment: What does "distributed id supplier" means? Do you mean we use another map to store full ids of cluster. So that what happen when data is growth up ( thoundsand millions entries)?

Comment: @lamxung55 (Disclaimer: Never tried this) I was referring something like Hazelcast CP IAtomicLong as an id supplier.

Comment: Still exists problem: Id value will repeat after an undefined time --> duplication occurs